# The getter ClipBehavior isn't defined for the class 'Stack'

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, sdk

I'm trying to run my app which Contains a "Stack" but it gives me an error which is:

```
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/convex_bottom_bar-2.6.0/lib/src/stack.dart:43:25: Error: The getter 'ClipBehavior' isn't defined for the class 'Stack'.
 - 'Stack' is from 'package:convex_bottom_bar/src/stack.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/convex_bottom_bar-2.6.0/lib/src/stack.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'ClipBehavior'.
          clipBehavior: ClipBehavior,
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/convex_bottom_bar-2.6.0/lib/src/stack.dart:53:21: Error: The getter 'ClipBehavior' isn't defined for the class 'Stack'.
 - 'Stack' is from 'package:convex_bottom_bar/src/stack.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/convex_bottom_bar-2.6.0/lib/src/stack.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'ClipBehavior'.
      clipBehavior: ClipBehavior,
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/convex_bottom_bar-2.6.0/lib/src/stack.dart:70:25: Error: The getter 'ClipBehaviorehavior' isn't defined for the class '_RenderStack'.
 - '_RenderStack' is from 'package:convex_bottom_bar/src/stack.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/convex_botvex_bottom_bar-2.6.0/lib/src/stack.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'ClipBehavior'.
          clipBehavior: ClipBehavior,
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        26.5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

my flutter doctor is all good with no errors and my flutter sdk is at the latest version. my teammate's app works fine with her. Help please

Answer (score 0):

As the error is saying that you are using the a variable named ClipBehaviour
where you should be using a variable of class Clip(your friend's code might be working because he had defined a variable of name ClipBehaviour in his code while you have not)

```
   Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: const <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            width: 100.0,
            height: 100.0,
          ),
        ],
      );
```

just like this see if it helps

Comment: it didn't work, we both have the exact same code. I added the (clipBehavior: Clip.none,) but still the same issues. Any more ideas?

Comment: Have you named any of your other classes Clip?? cause the only other reason i can think this is happening is because u have named any widget or class Clip and flutter thinks you want to override the existing Clip class and gives you an error. this is the only thing i can think of.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the trick . thanks

```
  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
```